# How to build a matrix like this in Latex?

Tags: matrices, labels

I've tried a lot of stuff to build something like that but I couldn't put the rows labels LKC1 and LKC2 and even not the matrices labels Y, V and J.

```
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:analise_nodal_circuito_exemplo_LKC3}
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1}\\
    -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix} 
    V_1\\
    V_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    I_S\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of idle curiosity: Why are you using a `gather` environment instead of, say, an `equation` environment?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. You will have a perfect alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
  \mathrm{LKC}_1 & \dfrac{1}{R_1}  & -\dfrac{1}{R_1}               
& \Block{2-1}{\cdot} & V_1 & \Block{2-1}{=} & I_s \\
  \mathrm{LKC}_2 & -\dfrac{1}{R_1} & \dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2} 
& & V_2 & & 0 \\
  & \Block{1-2}{Y} & & & v & & J
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-2}{2-3}]
  \SubMatrix[{1-5}{2-5}]
  \SubMatrix[{1-7}{2-7}]
\end{NiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? Note that I've deliberately replaced the 5 `\frac{1}{X}` expression with `X^{-1}` expressions, in order to even out the symbol sizes across the matrix and the vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % 'bmatrix' & 'matrix' environments, '\underset' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % '\addlinespace' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:analise_nodal_circuito_exemplo_LKC3}
\begin{matrix}
  \scriptstyle \mathrm{LKC}_1 \\ \addlinespace \scriptstyle \mathrm{LKC}_2
\end{matrix}
\underset{\raisebox{-1ex}{$\scriptstyle Y$}}{%
  \begin{bmatrix} 
      R_1^{-1} & -R_1^{-1}   \\ \addlinespace
     -R_1^{-1} &  R_1^{-1}+R_2^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}}
\cdot
\underset{\raisebox{-1ex}{$\scriptstyle v$}}{%
  \begin{bmatrix} 
      V_1\\ \addlinespace V_2
  \end{bmatrix}}
=
\underset{\raisebox{-1ex}{$\scriptstyle J$}}{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
      I_S\\ \addlinespace 0
  \end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```